# Laravel password reset "No Sender"

Tags: email, laravel

When I do a password reset in Laravel 5.1, I get the email, but it says "No Sender" in the title.

Is there a way to specify the sender from somewhere for password reset emails? Apart from the sender, I assume Laravel should automatically uses the email settings as specified in the config files? It's strange because when I set the Laravel mail config to use the 'mail' driver, I get bounced emails saying I can't send from a dynamic address (which is to be expected on dev),  but still the password reset emails go through. Shouldn't email reset use the same config settings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, Alexey Mezenin's answer is almost there, however, one big no no is overwriting the core files as any future updates can break functionality.

As your `PasswordController` should be using the `ResetsPassword` trait you should be able to just overwrite any methods from `ResetsPassword` trait in your `PasswordController`.

For example, adding your own `from` and `subject` line to emails is a simple case of finding the relevant function in your trait, copy and pasting into your PasswordController and amending it.

Here is an example `PasswordController` with a function that over writes the `sendResetLinkEmail()` function.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Mail\Message;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetsPasswords;

class PasswordController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Password Reset Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller is responsible for handling password reset requests
    | and uses a simple trait to include this behavior. You're free to
    | explore this trait and override any methods you wish to tweak.
    |
    */

    use ResetsPasswords;

    /**
     * Create a new password controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Send a reset link to the given user.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function sendResetLinkEmail(Request $request)
    {

        $this->validate($request, ['email' => 'required|email']);

        $broker = $this->getBroker();

        $response = Password::broker($broker)->sendResetLink($request->only('email'), function (Message $message) {
            $message->subject($this->getEmailSubject());
            $message->from(env('MAIL_FROM'), env('APP_NAME'));
        });

        switch ($response) {
            case Password::RESET_LINK_SENT:
                return $this->getSendResetLinkEmailSuccessResponse($response);

            case Password::INVALID_USER:
            default:
                return $this->getSendResetLinkEmailFailureResponse($response);
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Rajkumar has a better answer.

Comment: @ChrisBratherton how to use 'sendResetLinkEmail' inside the 'login.blade'

Answer (score 14):

Jack, you can set in the `From` attributes for `email id` and `name` in `config/mail.php`. I too had the same problem and just got it sorted, as i mentioned above.

Comment: thank you! Finally this was the last step for getting AWS SES to work on L5.6

Answer (score 6):

@SeriousJelly Answer Update for Laravel 5.2

in your Auth `PasswordController` Override `resetEmailBuilder` Method

```
class PasswordController extends Controller
{
    protected function resetEmailBuilder()
    {
        return function (Message $message) {
            $message->subject($this->getEmailSubject());
            $message->from('you@email.com', 'you');
        };
    }
}
```

This might help someone

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a better solution, but you could manually add code into `\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetPasswords.php`, after this line:

```
$message->subject($this->getEmailSubject()); // this is line 66
```

Add something like this:

```
$message->from('my@email.com', 'My Site');
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/mail#sending-mail

Answer (score 0):

Old question but in Laravel 10 in 2023, we handle this easily filling those fields on .env file

MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS="hello@example.com" 
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

Now if you wanna override and write your own email solution you can pass a closure callback function on line 47 of PasswordResetLinkController, it took me a while to learn it.

```
 $status = Password::sendResetLink(
        $request->only('email'),
        function ($user, $token) {
            $this->sendResetEmail($user->email, $token)

            return Password::RESET_LINK_SENT;
        }
    );
```